# JointJS: How can you create a oneSide link with 2 different sides

Tags: jointjs

I am trying to create a link that links from one shape with a fixed side to another with a different fixed side. Is this possible?

```
link.router('oneSide', {
    side: 'top',
    padding: 30
});
```

https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.1/joint.html#routers.oneSide

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure 'oneSide' should even be in the routers because in the [documentation](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.2/joint.html#routers.custom) the router only defines the middle points of the path not the start and end.

> In either case, the router function must return an array of route points that the link should go through **(not including the start/end connection points)**. The function is expected to have the form function(vertices, args, linkView)

I found out that in defining the links you can specify the anchor which is basically the start and end point. For the shapes there some [built-in anchors](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.2/joint.html#anchors). We have to use 'left' and 'right' for this case.

Here is my code. It's in TypeScript but I'm sure you can convert it to JS easily if you need to.

```
makeLink(parentElementLabel, childElementLabel) {
return new joint.shapes.standard.Link({
  source: {
    id: parentElementLabel,
    anchor: {
      name: 'right'
    }
  },
  target: {
    id: childElementLabel,
    anchor: {
      name: 'left'
    }
  },
  router: {
    name: 'normal'
  },
  attrs: {
    line: {
      stroke: 'black',
      cursor: 'default',
    },
    wrapper: {
      cursor: 'default'
    }
  },
  // smooth: true,
});
}
```